# Loop Or For Statement To Add A Line Break In Cells Of Selection If It Is In A Certain Row

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully that title makes sense.

I have a selection of cells I need to add a line break to, but only if that cell is in specific columns (C,E, and H). The selection will then be copied to Outlook, but I've already figured that part out. So far this is all I have:

```
Sub Mail_Selected_Changes()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim Signature As String

    Set rng = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    'Only the visible cells in the selection
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'You can also use a fixed range if you want
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").Range("D4:D12").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected" & _
               vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Body of message
    StrBody = "Hey Demi," & "<br>" & _
              " " & "<br>" & _
              "Here is a list of changes:" & "<br><br><br>"

    'Signature
    Signature = " " & "<br>" & _
                " " & "<br>" & _
                "Thanks!" & "<br>" & _
                " " & "<br>" & _
                " " & "<br><br><br>"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "Email Address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Changes"
        .HTMLBody = StrBody & RangetoHTML(rng) & Signature
        .Display   'or use .Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub


Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)

    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Basically I need to turn this:

[image]

Into this:

[image]

I will be adding this loop or for statement to the code from [Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/amail4.htm)

I've been trying for weeks now to figure this out but can't. Any help will be much appreciated!

While this isn't correct I was thinking something like:

```
If Selection.cell Is In columns(A,C,D)
     Then Selection.cell = vbCrLf & Selection.cell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO I've never been a fan of that custom function - if you're okay with a static range solution, then this would work out fine:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Mail_Selected_Changes()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim StrBody As String
    Dim Signature As String
    Dim mybody As String
    Dim i As Long

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
        mybody = mybody & Cells(i, 3).Value & "<br>" & _
                Cells(i, 5).Value & "<br>" & _
                Cells(i, 8).Value & " " & Cells(i, 9).Value & " " & Cells(i, 10).Value & " " & Cells(i, 11).Value & " " & Cells(i, 12).Value & _
                "<br><br>"
    Next i

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    'Body of message
    StrBody = "Hey Demi," & "<br>" & _
              " " & "<br>" & _
              "Here is a list of changes:" & "<br><br>"

    'Signature
    Signature = " " & "<br>" & _
                " " & "<br>" & _
                "Thanks!" & "<br>" & _
                " " & "<br>" & _
                " " & "<br><br><br>"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "Email Address"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Changes"
        .HTMLBody = StrBody & mybody & Signature
        .Display   'or use .Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

This code turns this:

[image: img1]

Into this:

[image: img2]

Just note that it's making a new section for every line in that section (not what's highlighted). This will not work if your row limit exceeds the VBA string char limit, which I think is 2GB?

Comment: Thanks for taking a crack at this! Unfortunately I don't think a static range will work as the number of rows will be different every time.

Comment: The number of rows changing here won't matter, it's just static based on the column letters right now. If you have 5 rows or 100 rows this will work.

Comment: Ah you're right! Different approach than what I was thinking but this works. I really appreciate you're help!